# Sublattice VS lattice under the ordering of its superset

Tags: lattice-orders

Yet another question coming from the book *Lattice Theory : Foundation*, written by George Grätzer.

In the third set of exercises, he proposes the following one :

> Find a subset $H$ of a lattice $L$ such that $H$ is not a sublattice
>   of $L$ but $H$ is a lattice under the ordering of $L$ restricted to
>   $H$.

I am confused since I thought that being a lattice under the ordering of its superset restricted to oneself was **the definition** of a sublattice.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

Thanks again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not the definition of a sub-lattice.
It has to verify that property, but moreover, for each pair of elements $a$ and $b$ in $L$, the elements $a \vee b$ and $a \wedge b$, as computed in $L$, must belong to $H$.

Consider, for example, the lattice $L$ in the following diagram:

[image]

If you take $H$ to be $L$ except the element which covers the bottom, then $H$ with order inherited from $L$ is a lattice, but not a sub-lattice because, if you name $a$ and $b$ to be the elements covered by the top, then $a \wedge b$ in $H$ is different than in $L$.

Comment: Thank you very much amrsa for this quick and clear answer.